# Clone a div with jQuery Clone function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to clone a `div` without its value. Everything I've tried so far copies the value as well.

Here is my jQuery function

```
$('#add_more').click(function(){
  $('#div_to_clone).clone().insertBefore('#add_more').find('input').val('');
});
```

Comment: I guess clone does what it says it does, clone ... clear the values in the clone yourself if you want to make a change to the clone

Comment: please add your **div_to_clone** code for better clearance.

Comment: Its working fine, you have there just typo - `$('#div_to_clone)` should be `$('#div_to_clone')`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working fine for me:

```js
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    $('#div_to_clone').clone().insertBefore('#add_more').find('input').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_to_clone">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="add_more">Add more</a>
```

Well, I recommend you changing your `id` to a `class` since the value of `id` attribute should be unique throughout the page. You might be getting the issue in some browser due to duplicate id.

```js
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  $('.div_to_clone:first').clone().insertBefore('#add_more').find('input').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div_to_clone">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="add_more">Add more</a>
```

Comment: Yes ty for all the help.. seems like my browser had some cache issue :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your html code is similar to this.

```
<div class="ContainerDiv">
<div id=ClonethisDiv><input class="InputTxtBox" type="text" /></div>
</div>
<a href="#">clone</a>
```

Now,
 `$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
    $("#ClonethisDiv").clone().appendTo(".ContainerDiv").find(".InputTxtBox").val("");
});`

Hence on click, anchor tag u will able to get a copy of Div with Id='ClonethisDiv' and appended to the container Div.
Here while cloning(copy) input element with a class '.InputTxtBox', will be emptied and get copied. No worry! TextBox Values which already appended to container Div doesnot change.
Hope this will help you.